# Using global assets for multiple decks in Slidify

Tags: css, r, r-markdown, slidify

I have a project with the following structure

```
- master
    - deck1
        - index.Rmd
        - assets
        - libraries
    - deck2
        - index.Rmd
        - assets
        - libraries
```

I have applied some css modifications in `assets/css/` for each deck that I would like to apply to all the decks (there are more than just two). Ideally, I would do this by using one `assets` folder (and libraries) on the same level as `deck1` and `deck2` and then call on it from the yaml front matter. Like this...

```
- master
    - assets
    - libraries
    - deck1
        - index.Rmd
    - deck2
        - index.Rmd
```

I have tried this:

```
assets: {assets: ./../../assets}
```

...as well as every conceivable combination of `.` and `/` and nothing seems to work. That is, my css changes are not applied to each deck. Does anybody know how to accomplish this? Or does slidify only look in the same directory as the `index.Rmd` file?

Interestingly, I was able to make slidify put the libraries folder on the same level as the deck folders (and it seems to be being used by all decks) by using this in the front matter:

```
url: {lib: ../libraries}
```

...but this does not work for the assets folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to use a global assets folder in the manner outlined above. The key is to include the assets folder path in the `url` section of the yaml front matter. For example:

```
url: {lib: ../libraries, assets: ../assets}
```

This puts the libraries and assets folders one directory above the `index.Rmd` files. Like this:

```
- master
    - assets
    - libraries
    - deck1
        - index.Rmd
    - deck2
        - index.Rmd
```

This answer was provided by ramnathv (4/24/2015) in the github repository for slidify [here](https://github.com/ramnathv/slidify/issues/421#issuecomment-96103337).